# c# .net form similar to listbox but with categories

Tags: c#, .net, forms, categories

Hi all i spent some time to find a c# form which acts similar to this one

[link to example listForm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bmz6x.png)

1. it  must have a random number of self defined categories
2. A specific column of an entry row must be editable with a doubleclick or sth else (e.g. the description field of my example picture)

i have no idea which c# form fits.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about a DataGridView?

Image: http://d1g3ybcl16zbb8.cloudfront.net/datagridview-tutorial-3.png

Documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.aspx

Answer (score 0):

DataGridView: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.aspx